# Solr Highlighting not returned when wildcard included in "q"

Tags: solr

Problem - QueryResponse > highlighting is null when search has wildcard.

Example
q=Text* - does not return highlighting for the matched field
q=Text - returns highlighting for the matched field.

In both scenarios hl info to solr is same, only difference in the search query is "q" as above.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by setting hl.highlightMultiTerm and searching for Text-space-*